# VHDL nested generate statements: how to refer to label?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I have this code that attaches a label to components instantiated inside a `for...generate` statement. So far everything works fine:

```
outer: for index in 17 downto 0 generate
attribute RLOC of EX_do1: label is "X0Y" & integer'image(index / 4);
begin
  EX_do1: FDC port map( ... );
end generate;
```

However, I want the attribute only on instances 0..15. So I tried this:

```
outer: for index in 17 downto 0 generate
begin

  inner: if index < 16 generate
    attribute RLOC of EX_do1: label is "X0Y" & integer'image(index / 4);
  begin end generate;

  EX_do1: FDC port map( ... );
end generate;
```

Now I'm getting the error message `<EX_do1> is not declared`. I tried moving `inner` before the `begin` of the outer statement, but same result. How can I refer to the flipflop?

I assume it would be possible by pulling the component initialization into the if-block and repeating it again in an if-not-block, but I am trying to avoid redundant code.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you just had two `generate` loops, one for 17..16, and one for 15..0.

Comment: Dave: that is my work-around for the moment. But it requires me to repeat everything that is declared in the outer block twice. This bloats the code and makes it hard to maintain.

Comment: Yeah, VHDL is like that. I sometimes write scripts to generate my code for me. The `m4` macro preprocessor can help quite a bit, too. I'm not a VHDL expert by any means -- there may be a way to do what you want within the language.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 7.2 Attribute specification "...An attribute specification for an attribute of a procedure, a function, a type, a subtype, an object (i.e., a constant, a file, a signal, or a variable), a component, literal, unit name, group, property, sequence, or a labeled entity shall appear within the declarative part in which that procedure, function, type, subtype, object, component, literal, unit name, group, property, sequence, or label, respectively, is explicitly or implicitly declared." The two generate statements have separate block declarative parts.

Answer (score 0):

I found an old [comp.lang.vhdl post](https://comp.lang.vhdl.narkive.com/lWsZh4BO/how-to-generate-variable-labels-for-same-component-within-a-generate-loop) that led me to the [FAQ](https://tams.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/vhdl/doc/faq/FAQ1.pdf).

Section 4.2.3 seems to suggest that you can use one or more additional `for` loops to assign your attributes, by referring to the instances of your FDCs using the syntax `outer(index).EX_do1`.

I'm not set up to verify this myself — let me know whether or not it's helpful.

Comment: This does not work :-( although it would make a lot of sense if it did. `Illegal name in specification`. I think the FAQ article refers to configuring components but the same syntax cannot be used for attaching attributes.